# How can I use a C# NuGet library in a C++ project?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, libraries

I want to use a C# NuGet library in a C++ project. I'm assuming I'd need to write some sort of wrapper in C# to be able to use the DLL in my C++ project, but I have no idea how this works and how to include this DLL in my C++ project.

I've created a C# library project so far and written this code, which uses the Spire.PDF library so far. The reason why I'm doing it in C# is because it is free for C#.

```
using Spire.Pdf.Texts;
using Spire.Pdf;

namespace SpirePDFLib
{
    public class SpirePDFLib
    {
        public static void ReplaceInPDF()
        {
            // Create an object of the PdfDocument class
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            // Load a PDF file
            doc.LoadFromFile("xyz.pdf");

            // Iterate through the pages in the document
            for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get the current page
                PdfPageBase page = doc.Pages[i];

                // Create an object of the PdfTextReplace class and pass the page to the constructor of the class as a parameter
                PdfTextReplacer replacer = new PdfTextReplacer(page);

                // Replace all instances of a specific text with new text
                replacer.ReplaceAllText("STATEMENT", "Statement of: user");

                // Replace all instances of a specific text with new text and set text color
                //replacer.ReplaceAllText("Adobe Acrobat", "PDF Editor", Color.Yellow);
            }

            // Save the resulting file
            doc.SaveToFile("ReplaceAllFoundText1.pdf");
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need to use the DLL generated by building this code and include it in C++, but I don't know how. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By making a clr/cli wrapper. I personally prefer not too since .Net has such a different memory managment model. Another option is to write a .Net server (running in a seperate process) and from C++ send the data to that server for example by implementing a gRPC interface.

Comment: If you can change your C++ project to C++/CLR it should be fairly trivial. You should be able to just add and use nuget packages directly. But if you have a native application you would need to start the CLR to run any .Net code. If that is the case it might be easier to just find another library, or run the .net code in a separate process, or do something else.

Comment: Can you use a C++ NuGet library?

Comment: @JonasH  Unfortunately, I can't change the C++ program. It's a massive legacy application

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can't use the NuGet library in C++ as only the C# one is for free

Comment: Adding a dependency on .Net is a major change to your application. It may require significant changes to code, training, maintenance, architecture, installation, and documentation. Doing all that for something as fairly simple as a PDF library seem questionable to me. Are you *sure* there are no other free C++ libraries that fulfill your requirements? Are you *sure* doing all of the above will cost less than simply paying for a license?